# Are there specific laws regarding selling code that executes financial trades?

Tags: contract-law, software, securities

If I want to start a business selling custom trading code for e.g. stocks/crypto what legal aspects should I be aware of?

Are there general examples of the kinds of contract you might want to absolve responsibility for any trading losses?

The client/customer would always be the one actually running the code and ultimately executing a trade, so I am never trading with their funds or have access to their account in any way, I'm just providing/designing custom trading tools according to their needs.